# Custom Toobar in Angular5

Tags: angular5, tinymce-4

Is there anyway we can add a custom toolbar in Angular code?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-menu-button/
This is the link to custom toolbar.

I need to get this in Angular5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own configuration to the editor via our component for integrating TinyMCE into Angular:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/#usingthecomponentinyourtemplates

In particular please see the `init` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Michael is right but I have found necessary to be in the appropriate scope to define the callback function of the button. I have defined the configuration in the environment, as suggested above. The button functionality is initialised in the constructor of the component instead so I do have full access to my components variables and methods.

In `environment.ts`:

```
    tinyMceOptions: {
    toolbar: 'repo'
},
```

In `Component.ts`:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    tinymceOptions = environment.tinyMceOptions;

    constructor() {
        let component = this;
        this.tinymceOptions["setup"] = function setup(editor: any) {

            function repo() {
                component.myfunction()
            }

            editor.addButton('repo', {
                icon: 'browse',
                tooltip: "Browse Document Repository",
                onclick: repo
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For tinymce version > 5.x** you'll have to use `editor.ui.registry.addButton` with `onAction`

```js
editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
  icon: 'browse',
  tooltip: "Browse Document Repository",
  onAction: function () {}
});
```